# Maintenance job failed saying update is not necessary

Tags: index, jobs, maintenance

We have scheduled Rebuild index and update stats job weekly manner. However this job was failed with below error message.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

```
Date 04/26/2017 07:00:00 Log Job History (Database Optimize WEEKLY)

Step ID 1 Server ****** Job Name Maint: Views and Stats Step Name
Views and Stats Duration 00:00:02 Sql Severity 16 Sql Message ID 0
Operator Emailed  Operator Net sent  Operator Paged  Retries Attempted
0

    Message Executed as user: ******\DBAdmin. ...
    [SQLSTATE 42000] (Message 0) HealthwiseTW 
    [SQLSTATE 42000] (Message 0) Executing Create and Drop Index on tblVDURiskResult - current fragmentation :25% 
    [SQLSTATE 42000] (Message 0) Building Temporary Clustered Index [TMP_tblVDURiskResult_fldiVDURiskResultLink] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0) Dropping Temporary Clustered Index [TMP_tblVDURiskResult_fldiVDURiskResultLink] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0) Updating [dbo].[tblPersonnel] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) 7 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 0 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblMonLaundTrain] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) 0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 2 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblManHandTrain] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) 0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 2 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblLookup] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) 0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 1 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblFireTrain] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) 0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 2 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblDataProtTrain] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) , update is not necessary... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15653) 0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 2 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblCourseBookmark] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) 2 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 0 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblCourse] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) 0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 0 did not require update. 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15651) Updating [dbo].[tblContact] 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15650) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been updated... 
    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15652) has been upd... The step failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `update is not necessary` is coming from `sp_updatestats`

If I run it in a demo database, the abridged output looks like this:

```
Updating [dbo].[Votes]
    [PK_Votes__Id], update is not necessary...
    0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 1 did not require update.   

Updating [dbo].[Users]
        [PK_Users_Id] has been updated...
        [ix_Users], update is not necessary...
        1 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 1 did not require update.  

Updating [dbo].[Posts]
        [PK_Posts__Id], update is not necessary...
        [ix_Posts], update is not necessary...
        0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 2 did not require update. 

Updating [dbo].[Comments]
        [PK_Comments__Id], update is not necessary...
        [ix_Comments], update is not necessary...
        [_WA_Sys_00000006_07020F21], update is not necessary...
        0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 3 did not require update.   

Updating [dbo].[Badges]
        [PK_Badges__Id], update is not necessary...
        0 index(es)/statistic(s) have been updated, 1 did not require update.
```

Scott is right about the rest though, creating and dropping indexes is custom code, and you're not getting the whole story from that output. Something additional is happening causing the error.

If your job step properties have output to a log file, you can often find the full error in there.

[image]